# How can I use openCV to do the image pair?

Tags: android, opencv

I need to use openCV to do the image pair in android devices.
For example, I want the mobile devices to match the apple image.
When I open the application, the camera is opening and prepare to detect the apple  image. If it is matched, the "match" message will be shown.
Can any one give me some direction to finish it? Thanks.

Comment: this is not a trivial task. search for logo detection to get some hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match an image, you can using Template Matching or using SURF Detector in Open-CV. see the following links:

- http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html
- http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html